# How does java send informations?

Tags: java, sockets, flush

Tell me.

What heppens when I invoke Socket.getOutputStream.write(); then Socket.getOutputStream.flush(); ?
Because when I want to send more than around 8162 bytes It sends only bytes which can be placed in this size. And next bytes aren't sent.

Explain me please.

Comment: Can you post some code, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do Java and I may be wrong but my suggestion would be that Socket has a buffer for outgoing data and that approximately 8162 bytes is it's maximum size and that data in excess of that amount would be truncated from the buffer and therefore would not be sent